# generating jpa metamodels for entities written in groovy

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, groovy

I faced a problem with generating JPA Metamodels for entities written in Groovy.

For Java it works as expected using maven plugin and hibernate's jpa-modelgen.

It seems like jpa-modelgen doesn't support generation of resources based on package not from java sources.

for example, I can generate querydsl classes for groovy using generic interface like this

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>GenQueryBean</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jpa-export</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <targetFolder>target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
                        <packages>
                            <package>com.project</package>
                        </packages>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But I didn't find any generator that accepts  arguments.

Are there are any alternative ways to generate JPA Metamodel classes ?